# asp.net mvc custom view create template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can add a new view to my mvc project by right clickt to action method in controller class.

[image]

There are Empty, Create, List Template select options.

[image]

But these are standart templates that asp.net team specified. I want to create my own template and use it.

Is this possible?

Comment: [How to Create Custom Scaffold Templates in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

By using t4 template, you can do it.

Scott Hanselman wrote good post here : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx

This would also help you : https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/